# Retrieve items beyond current date

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am working with PHP and MySQL and would like to retrieve queries based upon following criteria:

Where book_title = the search query book result OR book_keyword = search query result

AND

where the date of all the books retrieve is greater than of today.

This what I have brainstormed but does not seem to properly, in the sense that everything works well except filtering out the date (where it does show books with date older than the current date).

```
  $get_crs = mysql_query("select * from books 
                          where book_title like '%$search_query%' 
                            OR book_keywords like '%$search_query%' 
                            AND book_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY book_date1");
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a precedence issue. `AND` takes precedence over `OR` so to the DB engine your query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM books
 WHERE ( book_title LIKE '%$search_query%' )
    OR ( book_keywords LIKE '%$search_query%'
     AND book_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() )
 ORDER BY book_date1
```

You need to force the correct precedence by doing the following (parenthesis around the two `LIKE`s):

```
SELECT * FROM books
 WHERE ( book_title LIKE '%$search_query%'
      OR book_keywords LIKE '%$search_query%' )
   AND book_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE()
 ORDER BY book_date1
```

Alternately, you could do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM books
 WHERE CONCAT( book_title, '|', book_keywords ) LIKE '%$search_query%'
   AND book_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE()
 ORDER BY book_date1
```

On a side note, `SELECT *` is not a good idea. You should explicitly name the columns you want to return. Not because of security but because you may be returning more data than you actually need. You're also forcing the DB engine to look up which columns ought to be returned.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Like many, your response was incredibly helpful. For some reason ORDER BY book_date does not seem to work properly. Below is the updated version where showing only books past the current date works, but its not displaying them in ASC manner (from earliest date to the latest)    $get_crs = mysql_query("select * from books where book_title like '%$search_query%' OR book_keywords like '%$search_query%' AND book_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY book_date1");

Answer (score 0):

I would guest your problem is the "OR" op. Try put parentheses to force the "right logic order":

```
select * from books where (book_title like '%$search_query%' OR book_keywords like '%$search_query%') AND book_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY book_date1
```

Answer (score 0):

First off make sure the `$search_query` is properly sanitized or you could easily be sql injected.

To do your query add parentheses:

```
$get_crs = mysql_query("select * from books where (book_title like '%$search_query%' OR book_keywords like '%$search_query%') AND book_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY book_date1");
```

That will get the books which match either query in the `()` and then only get ones past the `current_date`.